# how to get the aggregate sum on a set of fields with the same values using mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, mongo-shell

I am trying to find the sum of documents which have the same values on a set of fields using mongo shell, these are sample documents,

```
{
"id" : "1",
"date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
"amount" : 697,
"name" : "vendor1"
}

{
"id" : "2",
"date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
"amount" : 380
"name" : "vendor2"
}

{
"id" : "2",
"date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
"amount" : 380,
"name" : "vendor2"
}

{
"id" : "3",
"date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
"amount" : 702,
"name" : "vendor3"
}

{
"id" : "3",
"date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
"amount" : 702,
"name" : "vendor3"
}
```

the query I have tried is,

```
db.results.aggregate([
{$group:{'_id':{name:'$name', id:'$id', date:'$date', amount:'$amount', 
count:{'$sum':1}}}},
{$match:{'count':{'$gt':1}}}])
```

but it fetched 0 records. Also I like to know how many such documents have been found, So I am wondering how to solve the issue.

Comment: You put `count` in the wrong place. It actually should be producing an error. Instead do `{ $group:{ '_id':{name:'$name', id:'$id', date:'$date', amount:'$amount' }, count:{'$sum':1} }}` for the $group` pipeline.

Comment: @NeilLunn thx, it works now. I also like to know how many result documents generated by using aggregate, how to do that?

Comment: how to sum the count in the query?

Comment: Test the length of the array returned ( when returned as an array that is ) or simply add `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }` to the end of the existing pipeline. Either way will give you a count of the number of things that matched. That question has been answered before, and your problem here was correcting the typo.

Comment: @NeilLunn like `db.results.aggregate([
{$group:{'_id':{name:'$name', id:'$id', date:'$date', amount:'$amount',}, 
    count:{'$sum':1}}},
{$match:{'count':{'$gt':1}}},
{$sort:{'count':-1}}]){ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }`?

Comment: Try `db.results.aggregate([ {$group:{'_id':{name:'$name', id:'$id', date:'$date', amount:'$amount'}, count:{'$sum':1}}},{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": {'$cond':[{'$gt':["$count",1]}, "$count", 0]}}} }])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
db.results.aggregate([
{ $group:{'_id': {name:'$name', id:'$id', date:'$date', amount:'$amount'}
                 , count: {$sum: 1} } }
])
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "vendor3", "id" : "3", "date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00Z"), "amount" : 702 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "vendor2", "id" : "2", "date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00Z"), "amount" : 380 }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "vendor1", "id" : "1", "date" : ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00Z"), "amount" : 697 }, "count" : 1 }
```